# SQL query to calculate totals from table that has overlapping/duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the total number of items from a table that has smaller building units. For example, let's say I have

**Unit_Table**

```
UnitId  StartUnit   EndUnit     QtyUnit
---------------------------------------
1       0           2           5
1       0           15          20
1       2           15          15
1       15          30          8
2       0           2           2
2       0           15          12
```

And let's say I have

**Final_Table**

```
UnitId  StartFinal  EndFinal    QtyFinal
----------------------------------------
1       0           30          
1       0           15
1       2           30
2       0           15
```

How do I populate the QtyFinal column with the correct numbers (28, 20, 23 and 12 in this example)? Let's assume that all building blocks necessary for Final_Table are in Unit_Table

The following query does not work:

```
;With Aggr As (
Select      F.UnitId
,           F.StartFinal
,           F.EndFinal
,           Sum(U.QtyUnit)      As QtySum
From        Final_Table         As F
Inner Join  Unit_Table          As U
        On  F.UnitId        =   U.UnitId
Where       F.StartFinal    <=  U.StartUnit
And         F.EndFinal      >   U.StartUnit
Group By    F.UnitId
,           F.StartFinal
,           F.EndFinal
)

Update      Final_Table
Set         QtyFinal = QtySum
From        Final_Table     As F
Inner Join  Aggr
On          F.UnitId        = Aggr.UnitId
And         F.StartFinal    = Aggr.StartFinal
And         F.EndFinal      = Aggr.EndFinal
```

The problem is that the Unit_Table has overlaps ((0-2) (2-15) and (0-15) for UnitId 1, for example), how do I eliminate rows 0-2 and 2-15 from the aggregate function for calculating 0-30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about processing `Final_Table` first. Then, for each row, we can look "the path" from Start to the End in the `Unit_Table`.

```
DECLARE
  VarStart NUMBER;
  VarEnd   NUMBER;
  VarQty   NUMBER;
  TotalQty NUMBER;

BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM Final_Table ORDER BY 1, 2) LOOP

    VarStart := i.StartFinal;
    VarQty   := 0;
    TotalQty := 0;

    LOOP
      SELECT EndUnit, QtyUnit
        INTO VarEnd, VarQty
        FROM Unit_Table
       WHERE UnitID = i.Unitid
         AND StartUnit = VarStart
         AND ROWNUM = 1;

      TotalQty := TotalQty + VarQty;
      VarStart := VarEnd;

      EXIT WHEN VarEnd = i.Endfinal;
    END LOOP;

    UPDATE Final_Table
       SET QtyFinal = TotalQty
     WHERE UnitId = i.Unitid
       AND StartFinal = i.Startfinal
       AND EndFinal = i.EndFinal;

  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I tried it and the result is:

```
UNITID  STARTFINAL  ENDFINAL    QTYFINAL
1       0           15          20
1       0           30          28
1       2           30          23
2       0           15          12
```

Of course, there's a problem when "the path" its not completed in `Unit_Table`, like this:

```
UnitId  StartUnit   EndUnit     QtyUnit
---------------------------------------
3       0           2           7
3       15          30          11
```

... But I don't know if it is possible in your application. Maybe this can't happend because is one of your requirement before inserting in `Unit_Table`.

Comment: Yes, I think I have to do some sort of looping for this, a single update clause is not going to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a correlated subquery or `cross apply`:

```
Update F
    Set QtyFinal = u.QtyUnit
    From Final_Table F cross apply
         (select sum(u.QtyUnit)
          from Unit_Table u
          where F.UnitId =  u.UnitId and
                F.StartFinal <= u.StartUnit And F.EndFinal > u.StartUnit
        ) u;
```

Notes:

- The `update` needs the table alias defined in the `from` clause.  Otherwise, it is a different reference to the table.
- If you are not familiar with `cross apply`, it is a lot like a correlated subquery in the `from` clause.
- A correlated subquery would be similar, but it would update *all* rows instead of only those that match.

Comment: Your query returns results, just not the correct ones. The problem is the incorrect where clause:

F.StartFinal <= u.StartUnit And F.EndFinal > u.EndUnit

Comment: @Rama . . . This query does not return results.  It modifies the underlying table.  I did change the units comparison to use the same logic as in your query.